# Vtiger adb array select statement

Tags: php, sql, vtiger

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vtiger_account inner join vtiger_troubletickets on vtiger_troubletickets.parent_id = vtiger_account.accountid where vtiger_troubletickets.ticketid=?";
$result = $adb->pquery($sql, array($recordId));
$customername = $adb->query_result($result,0,'accountname');
$customerphone = $adb->query_result($result,0,'phone');
```

Right now the above code works.  However instead of running the query twice is there a way to throw that into an array in 1 query.  I am not proficient in vtiger and adb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, You can use *query_result_rowdata()* method. This method will return an associative array of row. 
Please have a look on the snippet.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vtiger_account inner join vtiger_troubletickets on vtiger_troubletickets.parent_id = vtiger_account.accountid where vtiger_troubletickets.ticketid=?";
$result = $adb->pquery($sql, array($recordId));
$row = $adb->query_result_rowdata($result, 0);
$customername = $row['accountname'];
$customerphone = $row['phone'];
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks it works great.  Only thing I had to do was add an "a" to your "$db->" .  Confused me for a good minute though.  THANKS AGAIN.